# Is it possible to hike the Carpathian Mountains as a 2 or 3 day trip staying in Poland?

Tags: hiking, poland

I'm going to Warsaw to study for quite a while, on the 29th of September. My dad will be accompanying me for the first few days (nine to be precise). He's a fan of hiking, mountains and lakes in general.

He would like to visit the Carpathian mountains and hike for a bit. I was wondering whether this was actually possible to go to a decent part of the range and hike for a bit, without it being too time consuming or leaving the country? If so, what part would it be? Time is limited, maybe two or three days at most.

To be clear, we want to travel from Warsaw to a decent bit of the Carpathian mountains **inside** Poland and back in 2-3 days.

Comment: Are you asking if the bit in Poland is decent? Or if there's enough time to get there from Warsaw? Or if you can get to Romania and hike in a two or three day timeframe?

Comment: @GayotFow Travel from Warsaw to a decent bit of the mountain range inside Poland and back in a two or three day timeframe. Updated the question.

Comment: @GayotFow Well for all intents and purposes, we don't mind going to Romania, but we probably won't make that under such constrained timeframes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great idea! Hiking in southern Poland is very popular, and there is thousands of hiking trails all over Carpathians. It all depends what you like and how high you wish to go, because there is huge variety of mountain ranges from mostly forest mts like Beskidy or Bieszczady (around 1000-1500 m.a.s.l.) to higher more rocky ranges like Tatry (Tatra in English) reaching 2500 m.a.s.l.

Feel free to ask for details, I'm quite familiar with many of them so I can advise you basing on your preferences and experience.

Maybe one thing to have in mind is that currently the weather may not be as nice as in mid summer, but there are couple of nice days being forecast for this week.

Comment: We're pretty adventurous, but keep it real. Something casual with scenic routes would be quite nice. How easy it is to get there from Warsaw is also pretty important!

Comment: So I think Tatras is the best choice for adventurous guys :) You can easily get there from Warsaw by train to Zakopane, TLK trains are in reasonable prizes. If you go there by car, it should be quicker you go through Krakow via 7 / S7 road.

Comment: In Zakopane, right after you get out of train station, there are shuttles which will take you directly to mountain trails. I'd recommend you to go to Kuźnice which is very good starting point for interesting trails. Kasprowy Wierch (3 hrs walk or you can go up with cable car) is very nice place to go with beautiful views, although it requires good weather, otherwise you will end up in fog and clouds and see nothing :)

Comment: Besides Kasprowy Wierch, from Kuznice you can also go to Hala Gasiennicowa (blue marked trail) and then to Czarny Staw Gasiennicowy (beautiful lake surrounded by highest peaks) and from there to Koscielec or Zawrat, but these are more difficult and also more dangerous in case of bad weather.
Either way, I'm sure you will meet many people along trails, so you'll be able to ask them for help or tips where to go next, you have to see it yourself and judge how far you want to go.